# PHP - Mysql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

**When I try to run that code, that error appears:**  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

And I have no idea of what is the problem, someone can help me?

**CODE:**

```
<?php include_once("includes/head.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/connect/connect.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("includes/jquery.php"); ?>

<?php function friend_request_notification(){
global $db;
global $userid;

$userid = $_SESSION['userid'];

$query_id_see = "SELECT user_id FROM friend_requests WHERE user_id={$userid}";
$result_set3 = mysql_query($query_id_see, $db) or die(mysql_error());

$insert_table = "INSERT INTO friend_requests_notificated (id, user_id, user_id_requester)";
$change_table2 = mysql_query($insert_table) or die(mysql_error());

$select_table = "SELECT id, user_id, user_id_requester FROM friend_requests WHERE user_id={$userid}";
$change_table1 = mysql_query($select_table) or die(mysql_error());


if ($id_requests = mysql_fetch_array($result_set3)){

if ($id_requests2 = mysql_fetch_array($change_table2))
{
}

if ($id_requests1 = mysql_fetch_array($change_table1)) 
{
}



}
else
{
}


}





friend_request_notification();
?>
```

Comment: Your `INSERT` query doesn't have any values, just the fields

Comment: $insert_table .... Insert what? i don't see you inserting something there.

Comment: Switch to PDO with prepared statements and all your troubles will disappear

Comment: It'd better be tagged as a mysql question only. And you'd better provide only your SQL statements (for us to clearly check and help you if possible). And its title should be more specific.

Comment: You're brazilian, aren't you? By the way, welcome to stackoverflow (:

Answer (score 2):

Your insert query is wrong. You specify a bunch of fields to use, but provide no values:

```
INSERT INTO friend_requests_notificated (id, user_id, user_id_requester)
                                                                        ^^^^---??
```

It should be

```
INSERT INTO ... (...) VALUES (x,x,x)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: But I want to select the values from another table (to copy to a new table), so I had selected that table after..

Comment: doesn't matter. an insert query REQUIRES a values section. otherwise it's utterly pointless, the equivalent of serving an empty plate for supper. An insert query also does NOT return a result set, but you're trying to fetch from it later in your `if()` section.

Answer (score 1):

In insert statement you should give some values:

```
   $insert_table = "INSERT INTO friend_requests_notificated (id, user_id, user_id_requester) 
                     values (...";
```

Answer (score 0):

The INSERT statement will probably generate a syntax error.

The format for a *basic* INSERT statement is:

INSERT INTO [table] VALUES ([val1], [val2], ...);